# Stack pointer does not seem to increase when using pushad in recursive function

Tags: visual-c++, x86, masm, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

```
int x = 5;

void foo()
{
  long unsigned r[8];
  memset(&r, 0, sizeof(long unsigned) * 8);

  __asm {

    pushad;

    pop r[7];
    pop r[6];
    pop r[5];
    pop r[4];
    pop r[3];
    pop r[2];
    pop r[1];
    pop r[0];
  }

  printf("Register values: \n");

  printf("eax: %lu\n", r[0]);
  printf("ecx: %lu\n", r[1]);
  printf("edx: %lu\n", r[2]);
  printf("ebx: %lu\n", r[3]);
  printf("esp: %lu\n", r[4]);
  printf("ebp: %lu\n", r[5]);
  printf("esi: %lu\n", r[6]);
  printf("edi: %lu\n", r[7]);

  if (--x) { foo(); }
}

int main()
{
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

I just learned about the pushad/pusha operation and am trying to see how the GPRs change. However I seem to be getting a 0 print out for all of these except for r[0] which prints out numbers descending by 44 for each foo() call. Is that correct?

From what little I understand, shouldn't the esp register be moving every time I call a new function?

Comment: Normally you shouldn't use `pushad` / `popad`.  They're slow, and you almost never need to save/restore *all* the registers.  (Normally functions can clobber eax/ecx/edx).  Also, MSVC-style inline asm doesn't require you to save/restore registers yourself; the compiler saves registers you use if they need saving.  (They might now if your code is inlined into a larger function that already saved `ebx`, `esi`, etc.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, I see, I'll take note of that! The user-level threading assignment we were given only covered pushad and popad (we hardly know what the registers other than esp, ebp and eip do), so most of us are just going with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't quite do you what you want:

```
pop r[7];
pop r[6];
pop r[5];
pop r[4];
pop r[3];
pop r[2];
pop r[1];
pop r[0];
```

This doesn't actually compute the address of each LONG in the array `r` and pop the values to that location. it would have been like writing:

```
pop [r+7];
pop [r+6];
pop [r+5];
pop [r+4];
pop [r+3];
pop [r+2];
pop [r+1];
pop [r+0];
```

The inline assembly doesn't take into account the size of an array data element. Adding a value to the base of an array increments as if the index was in bytes.

It may be more evident as to what has happened. `r` will be the base address of the array (since it is on the stack it will be relative to `ebp`). `r+0` is the location of the first BYTE, `r+1` is the location of the second BYTE etc. You need to do the math and compute the index for each LONG. So it should have looked something like:

```
pop r[28];
pop r[24];
pop r[20];
pop r[16];
pop r[12];
pop r[8];
pop r[4];
pop r[0];
```